# customtab and contextcellmenu : button activation/desactivation

Tags: excel, xml, button, office-js, contextmenu

I have an Excel Web addin working correctly with :

one custom tab containing five control buttons
one menu control added to the contextmenucell..

However still some difficulties with activating and desactivating buttons.

'<'Enabled'>false<'/Enabled'>' XML instruction raises « invalid child element » Message

Comment: Show the XML for the ExtensionPoint and its child elements.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<OfficeApp ...>
  ...
  <VersionOverrides ...>
    ...
    <Hosts>
      <Host ...>
        ...
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <ExtensionPoint ...>
            <CustomTab ...>
              ...
              <Group ...>
                ...
                <Control ... id="MyButton">
                  ...
                  <Action ...>
                  <Enabled>false</Enabled>
...
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 0):

@RickKirkham`

```
       <OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
       xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
       <Id>7F8D6A98-CA41-474C-9DA2-D0A511EC822F</Id>
       <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
       <ProviderName>[Provider name]</ProviderName>
       <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
       <DisplayName DefaultValue="appx" />
       <Description DefaultValue="appx description."/>
<!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
<!--<IconUrl DefaultValue="https://appcommandicons.blob.core.windows.net/images/taskpane_32x.png" />-->
       <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icone appx.png" />
       <Hosts>
          <Host Name="Workbook" />
       </Hosts>
      <Requirements>
      <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
        <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.3"/>
        <Set Name="DialogApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
        <Set Name ="AddinCommands" MinVersion ="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/App/Home/Home.html" />
    </DefaultSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
<!-- Begin Add-in Commands Mode integration. -->
      <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <!-- Explications languages : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-owemxml/ef7df550-1528-4efd-b3b8-8b52ad2a8e80-->
    <!-- The Hosts node is required. -->
    <Hosts>
        <!-- Each host can have a different set of commands. -->
        <!-- Excel host is Workbook, Word host is Document, and PowerPoint host is Presentation. -->
        <!-- Make sure the hosts you override match the hosts declared in the top section of the manifest. -->
        <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
            <!-- Form factor. Currently only DesktopFormFactor is supported. -->
            <DesktopFormFactor>
                <!--"This code enables a customizable message to be displayed when the add-in is loaded successfully upon individual install."-->
                <GetStarted>
                    <!--Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Title"/>
                    <!-- Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Description"/>
                    <!-- Point to a url resource which details how the add-in should be used. -->
                    <LearnMoreUrl resid="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
                </GetStarted>
                <FunctionFile resid="Contoso.FunctionFile.Url" />
                <!-- PrimaryCommandSurface is the main Office Ribbon. -->
                <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
                    <!-- Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab. -->
                    <!---->
                    <!--<OfficeTab id= "TabHome">-->
                    <CustomTab id="Contoso.Group1Label">
                        <!--<Label resid="Contoso.Group1Label"/ >-->
                        <Group id="Contoso.Group2Label">
                            <Label resid="Contoso.Group2Label" />
                            <Icon>
                                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                            </Icon>
                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="residLabel" >
                                <Label resid="residLabel" />
                                <Supertip>
                                    <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label3"  />
                                    <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Lancer"  />
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Ouvrir_16x16" />
                                    <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.Ouvrir_20x20" />
                                    <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.Ouvrir_24x24" />
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Ouvrir_32x32" />
                                    <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.Ouvrir_40x40" />
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Ouvrir_80x80" />
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                    <FunctionName>action1</FunctionName>
                                </Action>
                            </Control>

                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="residLabel9" >
                                <Label resid="residLabel9" />
                                <Supertip>
                                    <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label4"  />
                                    <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Suspendre"  />
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Yo$_16x16" />
                                    <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.Yo$_20x20" />
                                    <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.Yo$_24x24" />
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Yo$_32x32" />
                                    <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.Yo$_40x40" />
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Yo$_80x80" />
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                    <FunctionName>action2</FunctionName>
                                </Action>
                                <!--<Enabled>false</Enabled>-->
                            </Control>
                        </Group>
                        <Group id="Contoso.Group3">
                            <Label resid="Contoso.Group3Label" />
                            <Icon>
                                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Réinit_16x16" />
                                <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.Réinit_20x20" />
                                <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.Réinit_24x24" />
                                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Réinit_32x32" />
                                <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.Réinit_40x40" />
                                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Réinit_80x80" />
                            </Icon>
                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="residLabel6" >
                                <Label resid="residLabel6" />
                                <Supertip>
                                    <Title resid="residLabel6"  />
                                    <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Réinit"  />
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Réinit_16x16" />
                                    <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.Réinit_20x20" />
                                    <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.Réinit_24x24" />
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Réinit_32x32" />
                                    <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.Réinit_40x40" />
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Réinit_80x80" />
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                    <FunctionName>action3</FunctionName>
                                </Action>
                            </Control>
                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="residLabel7" >
                                <Label resid="residLabel7" />
                                <Supertip>
                                    <Title resid="residLabel7"  />
                                    <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Sauver"  />
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Sauver_16x16" />
                                    <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.Sauver_20x20" />
                                    <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.Sauver_24x24" />
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Sauver_32x32" />
                                    <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.Sauver_40x40" />
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Sauver_80x80" />
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                    <FunctionName>actio4</FunctionName>
                                </Action>
                            </Control>
                        </Group>
                        <Label resid="Contoso.Group1Label" />
                    </CustomTab>
                    <!--<InsertAfter>TabReview</InsertAfter>-->
                </ExtensionPoint>
                <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
                    <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuCell">

                        <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="Autre2" >
                            <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label2" />
                            <Supertip>
                                <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label2"  />
                                <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"  />
                            </Supertip>
                            <Icon>
                                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.No$_16x16" />
                                <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.No$_20x20" />
                                <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.No$_24x24" />
                                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.No$_32x32" />
                                <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.No$_40x40" />
                                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.No$_80x80" />
                            </Icon>
                            <Items>
                                <Item id="couper">
                                    <Label resid="residLabel5"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="residLabel" />
                                        <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.couper_16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.couper_20x20" />
                                        <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.couper_24x24" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.couper_32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.couper_40x40" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.couper_80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                        <FunctionName>action5</FunctionName>
                                    </Action>
                                </Item>
                                <Item id="copier">
                                    <Label resid="residLabel1"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="residLabel" />
                                        <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Copier_16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.Copier_20x20" />
                                        <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.Copier_24x24" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Copier_32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.Copier_40x40" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Copier_80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                        <FunctionName>action6</FunctionName>
                                    </Action>
                                </Item>
                                <Item id="coller">
                                    <Label resid="residLabel2"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="residLabel" />
                                        <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Coller_16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.Coller_20x20" />
                                        <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.Coller_24x24" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Coller_32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.Coller_40x40" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Coller_80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                        <FunctionName>action7</FunctionName>
                                    </Action>
                                </Item>
                                <Item id="supprimer">
                                    <Label resid="residLabel4"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="residLabel" />
                                        <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Supprimer_16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.Supprimer_20x20" />
                                        <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.Supprimer_24x24" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Supprimer_32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.Supprimer_40x40" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Supprimer_80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                        <FunctionName>action8</FunctionName>
                                    </Action>
                                </Item>                                 
                            </Items>
                        </Control>
                    </OfficeMenu>
                </ExtensionPoint>
            </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
    </Hosts>
</VersionOverrides>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste the `<Enabled>` tag inside the control element:

```
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="residLabel6" >
  <Label resid="residLabel6" />
    <Supertip>
      <Title resid="residLabel6"  />
      <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Réinit"  />
    </Supertip>
    <Icon>
      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Réinit_16x16" />
      <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.Réinit_20x20" />
      <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.Réinit_24x24" />
      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Réinit_32x32" />
      <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.Réinit_40x40" />
      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Réinit_80x80" />
    </Icon>
    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
      <FunctionName>action3</FunctionName>
    </Action>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
</Control>
```

By default, any Add-in Command is enabled when the Office application launches. If you want a custom button or menu item to be disabled when the Office application launches, you specify this in the manifest. Just add an `Enabled` element (with the value `false`) immediately below (not inside) the `Action` element in the declaration of the control.

Read more about that in the [Enable and Disable Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands) article.

Comment: That's precisely what Xml refuses by throwing this "invalid child element" message. See the Xml page I sent

Comment: As a test I tried with an new Excel Web complement fresh from Visual studio 2019 with same result : <Enabled> is still an invalid child element. Any suggestion ?